# Emacs Custom macro/key-binding to add initials and datetime to code comment

Tags: emacs, macros, key-bindings, defunct

I'm looking for the cleanest way to have a language agnostic keybinding that will insert my initials + formatted timestamp e.g.:

```
--<my initials> (28 Oct 2013 11:38:20 AM)
```

into an Emacs buffer, so that I can initial my comments. I know I could create a function and create a keybinding to call it, but I feel like Emacs probably has a de facto way to do stuff like this, presumedly through the use of macros.

Comment: I'm not using any of these: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-outside-org.html but I'd imagine it would be the way to go (this let's you use some of the Org-mode functionality inside other modes, inserting a date from a calendar would be something like `C-c C-d` then, I presume.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F3</kbd> (start recording macro)

`--AA` <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-!</kbd> `date` <kbd>C-e</kbd> (insert text, insert output from `date` command)

<kbd>F4</kbd> (stop recording macro)

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> `my-initial-timestamp` (name the macro)

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> `...` (bind the macro to an appropriate key combination)

And finally, open `~/.emacs` and type <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `my-initial-timestamp`, which will insert the Lisp code to recreate the macro and bind it to the same key at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs does not have such a function, AFAIK.  There is function `time-stamp`, which updates time-stamp templates in a buffer, but that is not what you want here.

This command gives you what you requested.  Other time/date formats are available - see `format-time-string`.  You can also use functions such as `user-full-name` and `user-login-name`, if you want your name instead of your initials.  Here, I've just hard-coded your initials, `NF`.  This should work for any buffer where a comment syntax is defined (`comment-start`).

```
(defun my-timestamp-comment ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (format "%s NF (%s)" comment-start
                  (format-time-string "%b %e %Y %r" (current-time)))))
```