# How to insert space after cursor?

Tags: emacs

I am a new user of emacs.
I found some useful options that allows me to insert new line **before** or **after** cursor:  <kbd>C-j</kbd>  (before cursor),  <kbd>C-o</kbd>  (after cursor).

I found this very convenient in doing formatting text across lines.
Now, are there methods to **insert space after cursor** for in-line formatting?
Currently I have to insert space before cursor using <kbd>Space</kbd> then  <kbd>C-b</kbd>  multiple times just to return to the original position when doing formatting within one line.

Comment: @legoscia answered your question.  Remember too that you can easily do this kind of thing using a keyboard macro.  (Of course, if you want to do it a lot then you want to define a command for it once and for all - e.g., as legoscia has shown.)

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the tips. One question with macro: is there a way to define, store, and invoke macro that could persists after re-opening emacs?

Comment: @Minteh, yes, I described how to do it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19640686/113848).

Comment: See the Emacs manual, node `Save Keyboard Macro` - in particular, command `insert-kbd-macro`.

Comment: @legoscia Thanks. Well-edited steps.

Comment: @Drew Thanks. great reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is such a function, but it is easy to write:

```lisp
(defun my-insert-space-after-point ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion (insert " ")))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'my-insert-space-after-point)
```

This binds the function to <kbd>C-.</kbd>; adjust to preference.

---

Another way to do this is to record a macro, save it, and bind it to a key.  The steps to do that are described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640686/113848).